# Create job to send alert using sp_send_dbmail when table value greater than x

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-mail, alerts

**PROBLEM**

The `SMScounter.Counter` is used to accumulate usage from a service. The service has a programmatic cap of 1000. I would like to alert users when this cap is breached.

**TABLE CREATE**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SMSCounter](
  [Counter] [int] NOT NULL,
  [CounterDate] [datetime] NOT NULL )
```

**EXAMPLE DATA**

```
380, 2012-09-10 00:00:00.000
177, 2012-10-14 00:00:00.000
999, 2012-11-16 00:00:00.000
```

**JOB SCRIPT**

The script below is my attempt to create a scheduled job that will check every hour if the `SMScounter.Counter` is greater than 950.

```
USE DATABASEname
select (Counter) as CHECKVALUE from SMSCounter where smscounter.CounterDate  = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()),0)    
IF CHECKVALUE > 950

BEGIN

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @recipients=N'scott@mydomain.com',
  @body='1000 Daily SMS cap near', 
  @subject ='1000 Daily SMS cap near',
  @profile_name ='SCOTT',
  @query =
    'USE DATABASEname
     (select * from SMSCounter where CounterDate = GETDATE())'

END
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. How can I format `GETDATE` to examine `dd/mm/yy` and ignore the time part when reading `SMScounter.CounterDate`? (script above edited , works now).
2. How can I get the `IF` statement to work to compare `CHECKVALUE` to 950?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 standard edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `convert (date, GETDATE())`  to get just the 'date' part:

```
select GETDATE(), convert (date, GETDATE())
----------------------- ----------
2012-11-16 08:58:20.750 2012-11-16
```

And if you're only ever going to be comparing 'date' parts, it might be worth changing the datatype in your table to `DATE`, to save having to convert each time you query it.

For an `IF` statement you need to pass in a value to be checked, and then wrap the code to be run within `BEGIN` and `END` statements. Here's an example using the sysobjects table:

```
declare @cnt integer
select @cnt=COUNT(1) from sysobjects

if @cnt>50
begin
  select 'hello'
end
```

which will say hello if you've more than 50 objects in your DB

So in your case:

```
USE DATABASEname
go
declare @counter integer

select @counter=MAX([Counter]) from SMSCounter where convert(date,CounterDate) = convert(date,GETDATE())

IF @counter > 950
BEGIN
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
  @recipients=N'scott@mydomain.com',
  @body='1000 Daily SMS cap near',
  @subject ='1000 Daily SMS cap near',
  @profile_name ='SCOTT',
  @query =  '(select * from DATABASEname.dbo.SMSCounter where convert(date,CounterDate) = convert)(Date,GETDATE()))'
END
```

I've added a `MAX` function to your check query, as this will only return a single row containing the maximum value for that day, otherwise it'll return a random value from all the matching rows. If you're overwriting the day's value each time you write to the table, then it's superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not bad, but I would like to introduce you to a more real time one.
Instead of just checking the SMS counter every hour, wouldn't you better know when it first happened?

I would do the following:

- add a new column to your table - Alert bit not null default 0 - which will hold info if the customer was alerted about the high number of SMS. This is needed so that the customer isn't alerted for every insert/update > 950, but only for the first one.
- add a trigger on your table (after insert and update) that in case the value for the Counter is bigger than 950 will start the alert (set the alert column to 1 and send email).

The trigger would look like the following:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.RaiseAlert
    ON  dbo.SMSCounter
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    declare
        @cnt int,
        @today DATE = cast(GETDATE() as DATE),
        @alert bit;

    select @cnt = n.[Counter], @alert = alert
    from inserted n
    where n.CounterDate = @today;

    if @cnt > 950 and @alert = 0
    begin
        update SMSCounter
        set Alert = 1
        from SMSCounter
        where CounterDate = @today;

        declare @subject varchar(1000);
        select @subject = 'The sms counter is near!! It''s value is: ' + CAST(@cnt as varchar);

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='SQLAlerts',
            @recipients = 'xxx@xxx.com',
            @subject = @subject,
            @body = 'blablabla';
    end;
END
GO
```

A simple update would raise it and send the email:

```
update SMSCounter
set [Counter] = 988
where CounterDate = '2012-11-16 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this to work with the `@query` parameter so I used HTML instead

The script Audits Users logging in using "`sa`" or service accounts

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID ('AuditSqlLogins') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE AuditSqlLogins 
GO

CREATE TABLE AuditSqlLogins (
    [Counter] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login_name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [host_name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [login_time] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AuditSqlLogins]
    (login_time, login_name, host_name )

    SELECT login_time, login_name, host_name 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
    WHERE host_name not like '%APP%'  -- excludeds Apllication server logins
    and host_name not like '%WWW%'    -- excludeds Web server logins
    and database_id = 5               -- Specify the database you want to audit
    and login_name = 'Appadmin'       -- specify the account you want audited
    or login_name = 'sa'
    ORDER BY host_name desc

    DELETE FROM AuditSqlLogins
    WHERE host_name is null

DECLARE @counter integer
SELECT @counter = Counter FROM AuditSqlLogins                         

IF (@counter > 0)
BEGIN 

DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = CAST ( ( SELECT 
          td = login_name  , '',
          td = host_name, '',
          td = login_time,''

FROM AuditSqlLogins 

FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
              ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) )
       DECLARE @body  nvarchar(max);
       SET @body ='
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ea5685;
}
</style>
</head>
<H3>Audit Appadmin and SA Login Event : (Server Name)</H3>  

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" border-spacing="0" style ="text-align:center"> 
<tr style="height:15px; background:#ea8686">
<th border-spacing="0" style="padding:5px 15px;">login_name</th>
<th border-spacing="0" style="padding:5px 15px;">host_name</th>
<th border-spacing="0" style="padding:5px 15px;">login_time</th>
</tr>
'     
SET @body = @body+@xml+'</table><body>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients='youremail@yourwork.com', 
       @subject = 'Audit itsadmin and SA Login Event',
       @body = @body,
       @body_format = 'HTML' ,
       @profile_name='Your DB Mail profile'        
END
DROP TABLE AuditSqlLogins
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Martin.